# iPhone- Multiple pages

Tags: iphone, sdk, xib

I have a view based app going here with 3 different pages, I can't for the life of me get all the pages linked together correctly or completely.

Its just a home page with 2 buttons linking to the first and send page.... then back to the home page.

I have a mock up of what I am working with if someone could look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong here:

files.me.com/bolinger/0i1isa

thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can probably make do with a "Navigation-based Project" Xcode can generate for you. As for sample code, [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html) is a good place to start.

Basically, the [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class takes care of most of the bookkeeping; you just push or pop views as the user taps the buttons in your app.